# Regex - Match pattern even if surrounded by filler text

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find if a file of random text contains anything that looks like a SSN

```
^\d{3}\D?\d{2}\D?\d{4}$
```

The above does a great job when the text is explicitly 9 digits with or without the 3-2-4 delimiting. But this does not work if the text is surrounded by other characters.
eg.  A272-99-9999A

If I add the match anything to the beginning and end of the regex then it works for a lot of additional scenarios

```
^.*\d{3}\D?\d{2}\D?\d{4}.*$
```

The problem with this one is that it now matches strings that contain 10 digits
How can I search through for a specific pattern and ignore anything that's before and after it unless they are digits?

I've got a test environment at https://regex101.com/r/RnEquC/2/
Everything in the Positive section should match
Everything in the Negative section should not match
Don't worry about the False Positive section

Comment: `[A-Z]?\d{3}\D?\d{2}\D?\d{4}[A-Z]?` is this enough? https://regex101.com/r/RnEquC/3

Comment: No because this is matching sequences of 10 digits.  An SSN can only be 9 digits long

Comment: The surrounding text could be anything but numbers? or only letters?

Comment: Surrounding text could be anything, Letters, Special Characters, or Numbers.  If they ARE numbers then we should ignore it because it looks like a 10+ digit number.

Comment: You are aware your regex matches 9 digit number? and if you have surrounding numbers how can you tell which ones you want to keep and which don't if there are no delimiters?

Comment: How about [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eIBpWf/2)

Comment: You're right this isn't perfect. If there are no delimiters then it looks like a 10+ digit number and that means we can't tell if it's an actual SSN so we will assume it isn't.  If it is delimited with extra digits around it then this regex will not match.  eg. 1234-12-12345 even though 234-12-1234 may be the SSN.  I'm purposely ignoring this scenario because I'm hoping we don't store these numbers like that but have added it as a Positive scenario.  If you want to continue looking into it and figure it out I will accept yours as the answer.

Comment: @Toto, that's pretty good because it picks out only the numbers in question and is more performant than my other solution.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I just had to understand lookaheads and lookbehinds

```
^.*(?<![0-9])(\d{3}\D?\d{2}\D?\d{4}){1}(?![0-9]).*$
```